# Blocks nested too deeply

Tags: c++

I have some untypical problem. I make available to the user sendText() function. He can type e.g.

```
sendText( "mytext{newline}text{up}" )
```

{text} is a special key that user is allowed to send. There are a lot of special keys available.

So my first step was to get the string between {} brackets and to create:

```
if( _specialKey == "newline" ) {
    // action for VK_RETURN
} else if( _specialKey == "up" ) {
    // action for VK_UP
} else .....
```

example:

```
if( specialKey == "n" ) {
    // enter click
    unsigned short key = VK_RETURN;
    inputs.push_back( keyDown( key ) );
    inputs.push_back( keyUp( key ) );

    return 2;
} else if( specialKey == "n+" ) {
    // enter down
    inputs.push_back( keyDown( VK_RETURN ) );

    return 2;
} else if( specialKey == "n-" ) {
    // enter up
    inputs.push_back( keyUp( VK_RETURN ) );

    return 2;
} else if( specialKey == "t" ) {
    // tabulator click
    unsigned short key = VK_TAB;
    inputs.push_back( keyDown( key ) );
    inputs.push_back( keyUp( key ) );

    return 2;
} else if( specialKey == "t+" ) {
    // tabulator down
    inputs.push_back( keyDown( VK_TAB ) );

    return 2;
} else if( specialKey == "t-" ) {
    // tabulator up
    inputs.push_back( keyUp( VK_TAB ) );

    return 2;
} else if( specialKey == "caps" ) {
    // caps lock click
    unsigned short key = VK_CAPITAL;
    inputs.push_back( keyDown( key ) );
    inputs.push_back( keyUp( key ) );

    return 2;
} else if( specialKey == "caps+" ) {
    // caps lock down
    inputs.push_back( keyDown( VK_CAPITAL ) );

    return 2;
} else if( specialKey == "caps-" ) {
    // caps lock up
    inputs.push_back( keyUp( VK_CAPITAL ) );

    return 2;
} else if( specialKey == "ralt" ) {
    // right alt click
    unsigned short key = VK_RMENU;
    inputs.push_back( keyDown( key ) );
    inputs.push_back( keyUp( key ) );

    return 2;
} else if( specialKey == "ralt+" ) {
    // right alt down
    inputs.push_back( keyDown( VK_RMENU ) );

    return 2;
} else if( specialKey == "ralt-" ) {
    // right alt up
    inputs.push_back( keyUp( VK_RMENU ) );

    return 2;
} else if( specialKey == "lalt" ) {
    // right alt click
    unsigned short key = VK_LMENU;
    inputs.push_back( keyDown( key ) );
    inputs.push_back( keyUp( key ) );

    return 2;
} else if( specialKey == "lalt+" ) {
    // right alt down
    inputs.push_back( keyDown( VK_LMENU ) );

    return 2;
} else if( specialKey == "lalt-" ) {
    // right alt up
    inputs.push_back( keyUp( VK_LMENU ) );

    return 2;
} else if( specialKey == "rctrl" ) {
    // right alt click
    unsigned short key = VK_RCONTROL;
    inputs.push_back( keyDown( key ) );
    inputs.push_back( keyUp( key ) );

    return 2;
} else if( specialKey == "rctrl+" ) {
    // right alt down
    inputs.push_back( keyDown( VK_RCONTROL ) );

    return 2;
} else if( specialKey == "rctrl-" ) {
    // right alt up
    inputs.push_back( keyUp( VK_RCONTROL ) );

    return 2;
} else if( specialKey == "lctrl" ) {
```

but the compiler said:

```
fatal error C1061: compiler limit : blocks nested too deeply
```

My first idea to solve it was to define a map that will store all special keys (as a string) that maps to some integer. Then I could do:

```
switch( map[key] ) {
    case 0:
    ...
}
```

but I'm not sure if the compiler won't complain about it too. There's a lot of to change, so I don't want to change it for no results.

Or maybe do you have some other better ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: How many `else if` statements do you have? Did you try a `map` of `string`==>`action` eliminating the if/switch entirely?

Comment: C1061 is "Nesting of code blocks exceeds the limit of 128 nesting levels. Simplify nesting.".  You have 128 nested blocks of code?  Either you have some horrific code there, or you have macros adding lots of unnecessary blocks.  Try refactoring your code by splitting it up into helper functions etc.

Comment: Try using an array of key names and function pointers that do the relevant actions, then use a loop to find the key (binary search?  hash even?) and perform the action.

Comment: uhm, 156 functions? that's a lot, I put an example if-else in my post

Comment: @tobi maybe you should break these into two functions? That can break the nesting in half.

Comment: There's also the dirty trick; remove an else about half-way through the list of `else if` blocks.  It has performance implications; think about it and whether it is sensible.  It is a short term hack that will get you through; it is not a long term solution.

Comment: @tobi I think this illustrates your code quite well: http://i.imgur.com/9hKqK.jpg Now, go and try to come up with a smarter implementation.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion of the `map` of strings versus function pointers.

Comment: I'm very tempting to say this is a suitable job for regex...

Comment: C2011 requires 127 levels of nested blocks; C++2011 requires 256 (Appendix B, Implementation Limits) and so did C++1998.  It looks like the C++ compiler has a C and not C++ limitation.

Comment: There is this amazing new thing you can do with C++.  It's called "Object Oriented Programming".  You should try it some time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it's a Visual Studio 2010 Professional - if you wish to know.

Comment: 156 functions isn't nearly as bad as 156 `else`s.

Comment: Since you are doing a 'return' after each test when the condition is successful, you don't need an 'else', just do a series of 'if's. The chain will terminate as soon as you do a 'return', and the following 'if's will not be executed.

Comment: @PaulTomblin: Out of interest: How do you suggest using OOP to solve this?

Comment: @Moberg personally I'd use a dictionary/hash with a key of the "specialKey" value and a value of a function to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little bit OOP  instead pointer to functions way.

```
class ICommand
{
  public:
  virtual void execute() const =0;
  virtual void ~ICommand(){};
};

class KeyUpCommand : public ICommand
{
  DWORD key_; //not suare about win api here
  public:
  KeyUpCommand(key) : key_(key) {};
  virtual void execute() const
  {
     keyUp(key_);
  };
};

class KeyDownCommand : public ICommand
{
  DWORD key_; //not suare about win api here
  public:
  KeyDownCommand(key) : key_(key) {};
  virtual void execute() const
  {
     keyDown(key_);
  };
};


int main()
{
  std::map<std::string, ICommand *> commands;
  commands["t-"]=new KeyUpCommand(VK_TAB);

  //execute now
  std::map<std::string, ICommand *>::const_iterator iter = commands.find(_specialKey);
  iter->second->execute();
};
```

Comment: I like the solution the most.

Comment: Modified the answer that had some "copy-pasted" bug ;)

Comment: It was ;). but const_iterator should be ok, imho. I'am not sure about keyUp/keyDown signature.

Comment: and you can't type "virtual void execute()=0 const;" it should be "virtual void execute() const = 0;"

Comment: In reality, `const_iterator` may not work. The `execute` may itself would be needed to be non-const to actually "execute" something

Comment: Of course, in C++11 it should be a `std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<ICommand>>` to avoid the risk of memory leaks. And either way, I'd rather hide it in an extra class.

Answer (score 10):

You have more than 127 `else if` blocks. While this ought to compile and it's certainly a bug in Microsoft's C++ compiler, it's still a pretty strong smell that something is wrong with your code.

You're storing data in your control flow, the vast majority of these 128 blocks are redundant copy and pasted blocks. You shouldn't be doing that if it's at all possible not to. Separate your code and data, use control flow for special cases while refactoring all the common cases into a single hash map that deals with it as one type.

Comment: Both C++ 1998 and C++ 2011 standards require 256 levels of nested block (see the first item in Appendix B, Implementation Quantities [implimits]).  C only requires support for 127 levels, though.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a map like: `map<string, int>`. One element would be like `pair<string,int>("newline", VK_RETURN>`:

```
map<string, int> NameToKey;
NameToKey.insert(make_pair("newline", VK_RETURN));
```

And use the same in switch case like:

```
map<string,int>::const_iterator iter = NameToKey.find(_specialKey);
switch(iter->second)
{
case VK_RETURN: // Handle as "newline"
   ;
 }
```

Comment: yea, how could I don't think about it, thanks I like the solution more than pointers to functions. But are you sure that there's no limitation about number of cases?

Comment: C++ 1998 Appendix B Implementation Quantities says `Case labels for a switch statement (excluding those for any nested switch statements) [16 384].`  A mere 156 labels should not be a problem.

Comment: If that is the case, you can logically divide them. Like given a range of VK_LBUTTON (1) to VK_F24 (135), you can use one switch (preferably in some function), and another into different function and so on. But I don't see you would need to handle ALL keys, there would be most of them in `default` ~